# pywinauto doesn't identify control as a TabControl

Tags: python, pywinauto

`Inspect.exe` has identified the control as a TabControl, however pywinauto doesn't recognize the same. Image is as below** 
[Inspect.exe recognises TabControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klu6f.png)

`dump_tree` gives the following, the control type is `"C1.Win.C1Command.C1DockingTabPage"` which is a [component one tabcontrol](https://www.grapecity.com/en/winforms#controls)

```
Control Identifiers:

WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1 - ''    (L42, T31, R1334, B694)
['Alloy Configuration TypeWindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad11', 'Alloy Configuration TypeWindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1', 'Alloy Configuration TypeWindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad10', 'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad10', 'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1', 'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad11']
child_window(auto_id="AlloyTabDocument", control_type="C1.Win.C1Command.C1DockingTab")
   | 
   | WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1 - 'Alloy Configuration'    (L240, T32, R1333, B693)
   | ['Alloy Configuration', 'Alloy ConfigurationWindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1', 'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad12']
   | child_window(title="Alloy Configuration", auto_id="tabAlloyConfiguration", control_type="C1.Win.C1Command.C1DockingTabPage")
```

pywinauto's `HwndWrapper` object is not a tabcontrol:

```
>>> AlloyTabDocument  = addConfigWnd.child_window(auto_id="AlloyTabDocument")
>>> print(AlloyTabDocument.wrapper_object())
hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13965fa_r6_ad1
```

Comment: How do you create `Application()` object? Which backend is used? Looks like you're using default backend which is `"win32"`, but you must use `Application(backend="uia")` to make pywinauto doing the same things as `Inspect.exe`.

Comment: Thank you @VasilyRyabov this resolved the issue however now select doesnt seem to work. Could be because its a ComponentOne TabControl. Is there a way to access the tabitem properties such as rect to click the same.

Comment: Sorry for delay. We need to take a look at this with the live app. Just filed an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/695

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this. The demo for the controls is https://demos.componentone.com/c1demos/en/C1StudioDemoExplorer.exe , in this the control explorer-> Navigation and Layouts-> DockingTab

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this problem is MS UI Automation method [SelectionItemPattern.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern.select?view=net-5.0) exits without any exception, but actually does nothing with the given widget.

The solution is to select the tab by [ILegacyIAccessibleProvider::DoDefaultAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationcore/nf-uiautomationcore-ilegacyiaccessibleprovider-dodefaultaction) method.
This code works for pywinauto 0.6.8:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application
import pywinauto.uia_defines as uia_defs

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='wfControlExplorer.exe')
explorer = app.window(class_name="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1a8c1fa_r14_ad1", auto_id='Explorer')
overview = explorer.child_window(class_name='WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1a8c1fa_r14_ad1', auto_id='Overview')
tabs = overview.child_window(class_name="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.1a8c1fa_r14_ad1", control_type="Tab")
# tabs.dump_tree()
# tabs.select(2)
uia_defs.get_elem_interface(tabs.children()[2].element_info.element, "LegacyIAccessible").DoDefaultAction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have used win32 as the backend(this is default). use uia which gives control identifiers for ribbon and tabs.
eg:

```
x=Application(backend='uia').connect(title="window name",timeout=10)
    x.windowname.print_control_identifiers()
```